# Rails: Selecting tasks by month using Date::MONTHNAMES returns incorrect data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

Here are the associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, through: :user_tasks
  has_many :user_tasks
  has_many :completed_tasks, through: :user_tasks, conditions: { user_tasks: { complete: true } }, source: :task
  has_many :incomplete_tasks, through: :user_tasks, conditions: { user_tasks: { complete: false } }, source: :task
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :resources
  has_many :users, through: :user_tasks
  has_many :users
end

class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
end
```

I have a method called `task_notification` that takes a parameter of "past" or "future" and the method selects incomplete tasks based off the current month and the task deadline month.

```
  def task_notification(notification_type = "past")
    return if incomplete_tasks.empty?

    operator = notification_type.eql?("past") ? "<" : ">"

    current_month = Time.now.month
    incomplete_tasks.by_classification(classification).select { |task| task.due_date.send(operator, current_month) }
  end
```

Here is the Task `due_date` method:

```
  def due_date
    month = self.deadline.split(" ") - ["Mid"]
    Date::MONTHNAMES.index(month.first)
  end
```

Here is how a Task above looks like:

```
<Task id: 12, item: "Meet with guidance counselors and plan to take cour...", deadline: "August First", created_at: "2013-09-24 01:15:25", updated_at: "2013-09-24 01:15:25", classification: "Sophomore">
```

The problem is that since the `current_month` index is 1 (January) and the deadline is set to be in August (index of 8) the script thinks that this task is in the future and needs to be completed. These items should be set to show up in an academic calendar year not a normal calendar year.

Anyway to fix this?

Comment: Where are you even determining if something is past of future? How is the `task_notification` used? i.e. where is it given "past" or "future" (other than the default of "past"? Where have you defined an academic year so your code knows there is such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me from your question what format the `deadline` attribute of `Task` is in, but assuming that the month value extracted from can be guaranteed to be within the current academic year, then you can add whatever the academic year offset is to both the task month and the current month and compare the resulting values modulo 12 to each other.

Alternatively, and more naturally, you can turn the deadline date/time into a real date/time and compare it to now. The business with sending the `<` or `>` operators seems a little complicated for this use case.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that. The `deadline` is in the format of a string, for example. August End, December First, etc.

Comment: What's the `- ["Mid"]` about?

Comment: Some months have a deadline of `February Mid`